# Selenium: How to identify the button WebElement

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

On my webpage I have two buttons, how to identify which one is which?

```
<button onclick="addToSelected('newApplicationForm');">Add Strategy</button>
<button onclick="submitAddNewApplication('newApplicationForm');">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it's your webpage. Any chance you could put IDs to your elements? Would make it easier to identify them uniquely. If not, solution below.

---

You could use this **XPath expression**:

```
//button[contains(@onclick,"addToSelected('newApplicationForm');")]
```

Which will identify it by the javascript call, or you could try:

```
//button[.='Add Strategy']
         ^
         |_ May need to be replaced by text()
```

Which will match the content.

---

For the submit-button, you could try the same principle with identifying by javascript:

```
//button[contains(@onclick,"submitAddNewApplication('newApplicationForm');")]
```

or by content:

```
//button[.='Submit']
```

*Note: Some languages seem to use text() instead of the dot `.` to refer to the actual text in an element.*